# Unsorting with Bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I use Bibtex for quoting articles and I'm trying to typeset this :

```
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet \cite{safarevic54}.
\item Neque porro quisquam est \cite{feitthompson63} qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.

\end{itemize}

\bibliographystyle{siam}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

With my biblio.bib file :

```
@article{safarevic54,
    author  = "Igor Šafarevič",
    title   = "Construction of fields of algebraic numbers with given solvable Galois group",
    year    = "1954",
    journal = "Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR",
    volume  = "18",
    number  = "6",
    pages   = "525--578"
}
@article{feitthompson63,
    author  = "Walter Feit and John Griggs Thompson",
    title   = "Solvability of groups of odd order",
    year    = "1963",
    journal = "Pacific Journal of Mathematics",
    volume  = "13",
    number  = "",
    pages   = "775--1029"
}
```

And I get this ...

> - Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet [2]
> - Neque porro quisquam est [1] qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.

... while it would be more logical to have the numbers into square bracket inverted. Using the **unsrt** style, I don't have this problem anymore, but I don't like this style. So is there any idea for keeping **siam**, and changing this inversion ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can use `biblatex` with your required modifications.

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy the file `siam.bst` (on my computer it is `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/siam.bst`) to `unsrtsiam.bst` in the work directory.
2. Open `unsrtsiam.bst` in an editor and comments out the line `SORT` (line 993 in my copy):

   ```
   %SORT
   ```
3. Change bibliography style to `unsrtsiam`.